# Why is absolute positioning ignoring top padding but not left padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm trying to make the ripple appear where you click but it seems to place it to the right for whatever amount of pixels that left padding has. Anybody knows why?

Also if anybody knows some good way to remove the divs once they're not used anymore that would be great :)

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

function ripple(e) {
 var rpl = document.createElement('div');
  this.appendChild(rpl);
  
  var d = Math.max(this.clientWidth, this.clientHeight);
  
  rpl.style.width = rpl.style.height = d+"px";
  
  pl = window.getComputedStyle(this, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left');
  
  rpl.style.left = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft - d / 2 + "px";
  rpl.style.top = e.clientY - this.offsetTop - d / 2 + "px";
  
  rpl.classList.add('ripple');
  
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(b){
 b.addEventListener('click',ripple);
});
```

```css
/*custom fonts - Bitter, Montserrat*/
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Bitter');
/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;font-family: arial; box-sizing: border-box}
body {
 background: #212121;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center; padding: 85px 100px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.green {background: limegreen; border: 3px solid limegreen;}
.blue {background: dodgerblue; border: 3px solid dodgerblue;}
.orange {background: orange; border: 3px solid orange;}

button {
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  user-text-select: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #212121;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 18px 30px;
}

.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: scale(0); opacity: 0.9;
  animation: ripple 3s linear;
}


@keyframes ripple {
  to {transform: scale(2.5); opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<h1>Ripple Click Effect</h1>

<button class="green">Log in</button>

<button class="blue">Sign up</button>

<button class="orange">Subscribe to newsletter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, chrome has some problem when you just define min-width/min-height without width/height properties. Try to set eg. `width:150px` for the button and you'll find out that the problem dissapear. But if you want to keep `width:auto` you can try to delegate your click event and get all dimensions, mouse coords etc. like below:

p.s. I also added `pointer-events:none` (IE11+) for the `.ripple` so that there would be able to fire next click event over previous `.ripple` object. You can remove it and check out the difference.

p.s. 2 To remove previous `.ripple` elements you can use onanimationend event (IE10+).

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

window.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var wX = event.clientX;
  var wY = event.clientY;

  if(event.target.nodeName==="BUTTON"){
    var button = event.target;
    var getButtonPos = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var bX = getButtonPos.left;
    var bY = getButtonPos.top;
    var rpl = document.createElement('div');
    rpl.addEventListener('animationend',function(){
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    });
    button.appendChild(rpl); 
    var d = Math.max(button.clientWidth, button.clientHeight);
    rpl.style.width = rpl.style.height = d+"px";
    rpl.style.left = wX - bX - d / 2 + "px";
    rpl.style.top = wY - bY - d / 2 + "px";
    rpl.classList.add('ripple');    
    
  }
});
```

```css
/*custom fonts - Bitter, Montserrat*/
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Bitter');
/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;font-family: arial; box-sizing: border-box}
body {
 background: #212121;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center; padding: 85px 100px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.green {background: limegreen; border: 3px solid limegreen;}
.blue {background: dodgerblue; border: 3px solid dodgerblue;}
.orange {background: orange; border: 3px solid orange;}

button {
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  user-text-select: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #212121;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 18px 30px;
}

.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: scale(0); opacity: 0.9;
  animation: ripple 3s linear;
  pointer-events: none;
}


@keyframes ripple {
  to {transform: scale(2.5); opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<h1>Ripple Click Effect</h1>

<button class="green">Log in</button>

<button class="blue">Sign up</button>

<button class="orange">Subscribe to newsletter</button>
```